# Call to a member function where() on null using HasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a filtered list of related records using HasManyThrough. 
The unfiltered HasManyThrough works fine. However, because not all the records have relations (i.e HasManyThrough is null on some of the records), I'll get 'Call to a member function where() on null' error when trying to filter the results.

```
protected $appends = ['retention'];

public function getRetentionAttribute() {

    $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Attendance',
        'App\ClassCourseInstance',
        'course_id', 
        'class_id', 
        'id', 
        'id' 
    );

    return $this->attendance->where('checked_time' , '!=' , NULL)->count();

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your `attendance` method.

Comment: I think `$this->hasManyThrough` should be in a different function representing a relationship. Please view docs @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through